# Add mousewheel functionality to lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, mousewheel

I want to combine the `fslightbox.js` lightbox plugin:
https://fslightbox.com

with the `jquery-mousewheel` plugin
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel

to add mousewheel functionality so when the user scrolls up or down on the Lightbox it **changes to the next or previous photo**.

this is my js code but `lightbox.on('mousewheel')` it's not triggering,
any ideas on how to make it work?

```
var lightbox = $('.fslightbox-container');
lightbox.on('mousewheel', '.fslightbox-absoluted', function (e) {
  if (e.deltaY>0) {
      lightbox.trigger('.fslightbox-slide-btn-container-next"');
  } else {
      lightbox.trigger('.fslightbox-slide-btn-container-previous');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

html:

```
<div id="mygallery" >
<a href="./app/img/ilustraciones-1.png" data-fslightbox>
    <img src="./app/img/ilustraciones-1.png"/>
</a>
<a href="./app/img/ilustraciones-2.png" data-fslightbox>
    <img src="./app/img/ilustraciones-2.png"/>
</a>
<a href="./app/img/ilustraciones-3.png" data-fslightbox>
    <img src="./app/img/ilustraciones-3.png"/>
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start you have a syntax error, which the error console would confirm.

```
lightbox.trigger('.fslightbox-slide-btn-container-next"'); //<-- "
```

Secondly, you seem to be making considerable assumptions on what `trigger()` does and how it works, believing that you pass it a selector and it triggers a click event. That's [not how it works](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/). I think you mean:

```
lightbox.find('.fslightbox-slide-btn-container-next').click();
```

Comment: I understand, but still trying with your syntax change the lightbox won't pass to next/previous photo on mousewheel action

Comment: Typo on my part - I missed the `.` from the front of the seletor. If it still doesn't work, check that the element you're looking for with that selector is actually being found.

Comment: it's not working. I have added the console.log(event.deltaX, event.deltaY, event.deltaFactor); and if I check on console.log it doesn't even show anything

Comment: Then you need to do some debugging steps to ensure that the code is running in each gate, i.e. that conditions are returning true. Set up a Fiddle after you've done this if it's still not working.